# Azure Cloud shell requires storage account

Tags: azure, azureshell

We have a Azure subscription, one of my colleague's azure user account is working fine. He has created Registry as well as he has deployed a hello world image in it using azure cli.

But when i click on Azure Cloud shell, it prompts for resource group and storage account. even after selecting existing resource group and storage account that my colleague has created, there is one more mandatory field file share.

Whats the importance of it and can we give any name to it? is that also chargeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats the importance of it and can we give any name to it? is that
>   also chargeable?

You should create Azure file share, and it is chargeable.

You can find the request in the last line, like this:

[image]

In the last line, we can find the cloud shell requirement, we should create a storage account in that location same as your resource group(In my test require to create a storage account in Central India), and the storage account should be **LRS** or **GRS**.

Here a similar [case](https://serverfault.com/questions/891381/azure-cloud-shell-no-existing-storage-accounts-available/891503#891503) as you, please refer to it.

More information about deploy Azure cloud shell, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

---

**Note:**

We can't select existing file share in the configure page, need to manually **enter the name**.

Comment: So every account user has to create a file share even though they have a existing Resource group and Storage account right? and this will be one time task?

Comment: Not one time task, do you have permission of that storage account? In my test, I grant storage account Contributor permission of that account, works fine.

Comment: It is visible to me to select from drop down list of storage account. should i check anything else

Comment: On clicking the storage account details on dashboard i am able to see that i am a contributor in access control. is that sufficient or i need to check anything else?

Comment: can you find the file share in that storage account? does the storage account in the same region, could you please show me your last line in that cloud shell configure page?

Comment: Thank you for your share, I mean the last one, like this "cloud shell requires storage accounts in your cloud shell region...", can you find it?

Comment: Its like this for me --> Cloud Shell requires storage accounts in your Cloud Shell region (West Europe) to be LRS or GRS

Comment: Ok, please check that storage account is in West Europe? and the storage account type is LRS or GRS.  we can find them in storage account dashboard.

Comment: Its West Europe and LRS

Comment: can you find that file share?

Comment: As you can see file share is empty for me in the screen shot. should i populate this with something as i am logging in for the first time?

Comment: Okay Sure. Thanks a lot. So is this one time setup? from next time i can use same details right? and its specific to each user account right?

Comment: Yes, if the storage account have not delete, you can use that cloud shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses

Comment: @JasonYe I am not able to select use existing storage account option, it is disabled. Error in creating new storage account as part of process(I have rights to create storage account on that subscription) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715343/shell-azure-com-is-failing-in-configuration/