# Unable to open Cloud Shell because of Storage Account error

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azureshell

I am trying to open Cloud Shell by following below steps.

Click on **Cloud Shell** toolbar icon.

Click on **PowerShell** link from the generated window.

Selected **Visual Studio Professional Subscription** as that is the one and only available for me.

Clicked on **Create storage** button. Now, I am getting below error:

```
{"error":{"code":"StorageAccountAlreadyTaken","message":"The storage account named abcdefghijklmn1003200086 is already taken."}}
Can't create a storage account. Please try again.
```

I have created one separate storage account solely for this task purpose, but "Use existing storage account" option was not selectable.

The suggestions from [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275062/azure-cloud-shell-requires-storage-account) did not work for me.

Comment: `I have created one separate storage account solely for this task purpose, but "Use existing storage account" option was not selectable.` ... Have you selected the location of Cloud shell region same as that of your storage account?

Comment: This interface should appear when you have a subscription but no Storage Account. After that, this interface will not appear. You need to be careful not to create a Storage Account with the same name. Otherwise, it will report an error.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: I have not done anything specific to select the location of Cloud shell region. I could see my storage account location as "Central US, East US 2". Please suggest me how can I make sure that both Cloud shell region and storage account location, both are same.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this question?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am also not able to select existing storage account, any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

After unmounted. I can reproduce what you face now.

[image]

Click **Show Advanced Settings**, and customize a name of Storage Account and File share.(English part must be lowercase.)

[image]

Then it works fine.

[image]

**Original Answer:**

**StorageAccountAlreadyTaken** is a common storage account creation problem. It means that you are creating a storage account, but a storage account with the same name exists worldwide (the storage account name must be unique among all Azure accounts).

This error is telling you: You are creating me, a Storage Account. But you need to give me a unique name.

If the button for an existing account cannot be selected, then please do not use the same name when you create a storage account.

Comment: I am not even trying to create storage account. I think, you didn't go through my question to understand the issue...

Comment: @Ashokkumar I updated the answer. Try to create a Storage Account and a corresponding File share in the Central US like me.(Don't use the same name that I use.) See if it works.

Comment: @Ashokkumar After many attempts, I found out that I can't choose 'Use existing' at all on my side. There may be a problem with this button. Entering the created Storage and filling in the corresponding File Share and then click 'Create Storage' will actually mount the specified Storage. I suggest that you do not use a Storage Account that has stored a lot of things, otherwise the load time of Cloud Shell will become very very long.

Answer (score 0):

I will think that registering the cloudshell service in resource provider will solve this problem provided you are logged in the right subscription and under the right directory.
log into azure portal> select subscription>settings>resource provider> search for cloudshell>make sure it is register?re-register.