# shell.azure.com is failing in configuration

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azureshell

While doing something I got option to execute shell commands from azure portal. It required to configure shell.azure.com first time.

In first step it is giving option of selecting Subscription & create storage. When I select required subscription & click on create storage, it is giving error:

```
Error: 409 
{"error":{"code":"StorageAccountAlreadyTaken", "message":"The storage account named ... is already taken"}}
Can't create a storage account. Please try again.
```

[image]

I tried multiple times but no avail.

I opened `Show advanced settings` & tried to play with combinations but here using existing storage account is disabled(in advanced settings) and create storage is also disabled. 
[image]**strong text**
PS I have rights to create storage account on subscription, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face the same issue before. You need to **directly edit** (manually type the name) the existing storage account in the box, just ignore the using existing checkbox. It seems like a UI bug.

When you add the existing storage account on the UI, please note that the cloud shell region matches the storage account region. You can see the Supported storage regions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage.

Refer to the familiar threads,

[Unable to open Cloud Shell because of Storage Account error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620035/unable-to-open-cloud-shell-because-of-storage-account-error)

[Azure Cloud shell requires storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275062/azure-cloud-shell-requires-storage-account)

Comment: makes sense, thanks I will try later, in mid of another approach now